# How can I do this with OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a control that has an attribute like this

```
OnClientClick="checkfn( resultfn(boolval) )"
```

checkfn goes and displays a modal confirmation. And returns the results in resultfn(boolval) as either true or false.

How do I make OnClientClick take that value and return it. Eg. if resultfn(boolval) = true, then i want it to post back to the server, if it is false, i want to cancel.

UPDATE:

this is what checkfn does at the moment. See below.

```
function checkfn() {

                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Continue: function () {                           
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return true;
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

}

This doesn't work because checkfn is not waiting for the dialog-confirm box before it returns something. So my idea is that I would like to put things in Continue and Cancel functions to return to resultfn(boolval) a bool which onclientclick can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the JavaScript function called in `OnClientClick` "return" the value to the server, but you can populate a hidden input in the form so that in your server-side click handler, you can read the value:

```
OnClientClick="document.getElementById('hidden').setAttribute('value', checkfn(resultfn(boolval)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnClientClick="return checkfn( resultfn(boolval) );"`.  If you have validation, this may break the validation because it `return`s to early.  In that case, you want to only `return` if the result is false:

```
OnClientClick="var result=checkfn(resultfn(boolval)); if (!result) return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is on a submit button/link, change it to

```
OnClientClick="return checkfn( resultfn(boolval) );"
```

Try it this way

```
function checkfn(buttonUniqueID) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Continue: function () {                           
            $(this).dialog("close");
            __doPostBack(buttonUniqueID, '');
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Then change the OnClientClick

```
OnClientClick='return checkfn(<%= this.UniqueID %>);'
```

Comment: but this is only returning whether checkfn comes out as true or false. in my solution, checkfn calls a jquery widget which produces a confirmation box which then returns the results in resultfn(boolval)

Comment: @RoboShop: So what is the purpose of `checkfn`?  Why can't you just `return resultfn(boolval);`?

Comment: The way you have described, checkfn seems to return the result of confirmation. If so, this should stop the submission when the confirmation was cancel and vice versa.

Comment: hi, i have tried to update the question to be a little bit more specific. thanks

Answer (score 1):

@amit_g's answer is pretty close.  Since you're using a a jQueryUI dialog rather than window.confirm, checkfn() is executing and returning.  Try something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonUniqueId" ... OnClientClick="checkfn(); return false;" />
```

The above code will fire checkfn() and then cancel the postback.  This gives your jQueryUI dialog time to open up and present options to the user.  Next, use @amit_g's checkfn() to postback using the .NET Button, should the use decide to continue:

```
function checkfn(buttonUniqueID) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Continue: function () {                           
            $(this).dialog("close");
            __doPostBack(buttonUniqueID, '');
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than let jQuery make the buttons for you, add the buttons by hand, and use a link button as your Continue button.